# How to match with common cities visited in

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

The goal is to match the special and the normal and the condition is that they have a common city. The special's name should appear in Column E and the Normal's name should appear in Column F and they're being matched because they both are in the same city or have visited the same city.

So the data dump that, um, will be updated on a daily basis. So for example, Type Special - Caroline has visited in Cambridge. If there's also a Type Normal that has visited Cambridge. Hence both visited Cambridge and that's why they were matched.

All right. Another example is, um, let's see here, Regina. Is a special type. Now we want to match her with a type Normal. So in this case, there are no matches, so that would not appear in the outcomes.

Only those who have been tagged as a Special or a Normal can be matched. So the match always has to be between Special and Nornal and their names just have to appear here at the visited city.

Using FILTER Function thought it would work out, that will automatically detect a Special and a Normal when there is a common keyword in a city that they visited in, but it isn't working.

[image]

[GoogleSheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJr5PT4QDspxJkpgCFIK6K0hDlCQx3DhT9VUjba2nmw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: @player0 i just edited my post and shared a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:D17, "select max(A),B where D is not null group by B pivot D", 1)
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A17&"×"&B2:B17, D2:D17="special")&"×"&
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A17&"×"&B2:B17, D2:D17="normal"))), "×"),
 "select Col1,Col3,Col4 where Col2=Col4", ))
```

[image]